# How to split the returned value of a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, split

***EDIT*** Updated with working solution

I have a geocoded section of my website and it uses the user's IP to set a cookie with their city, state and zipcode. I want to print the zipcode to the front-end UI so I am trying to retrieve just that part of the cookie.

My cookie is formatted like this:

```
Miami%2CFL%2C33133
```

Currently I am retrieving the cookie with this Javascript function:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

var x = readCookie('location_data').split('%2C')[2];
alert(x);
```

How can I split the cookie so that only the zip code(3rd segment) is returned?

Thank you!

Comment: `yourCookie.split('%2C')[2]`

Comment: You have to apply `unescape` first, then split by ','

Comment: Thanks Johannes, that worked great, I've updated my question with the solution, if you'd like to add an answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks again!